# Can an Azure AD B2C custom policy set Application Insights operation_id using AzureApplicationInsightsProvider

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Is there a way to set the `operation_id` field - or other top-level fields like `session_id`, `operation_ParentId`, etc - in App Insights using [AzureApplicationInsightsProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/analytics-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)?

Using `PartnerClaimType="{property:PropertyName}"` only seems to set properties in `customDimensions` on the event, even if I use syntax like `{property:operation_id}`.

Similarly, using `PartnerClaimType="operation_id"` or `PartnerClaimType="eventOperationId"` just seem to be ignored.

Comment: Thanks @Dave and please follow the list of Technical profile supports the Application Insights property however using REST API you can achieve the requirement- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/technicalprofiles#include-technical-profile

Comment: @Jit_MSFT thanks, so the only way would be to set up an API that would perform the write to App Insights and have B2C call that API with the REST technical profile? If that's the case feel free to add that as an answer and I'll accept.